# Spring Boot @EnableAutoConfiguration exclude a class conditionally based on a property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-messaging

Is it possible to exclude a class from auto-configuration
based on the value of a property?
In my case I want to disable,
`MailSenderAutoConfiguration` in some case.
For example,
say I have this property `app.email.disabled=true` in my `application.properties`,
I would like something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class, ifProperty="app.email.disabled")
public class Application { .... }
```

I know I can declare a bean of type `JavaMailSender`
and use `@ConditionalOnProperty`,
but I already defined all email's properties in the
`application.properties` and
I don't want to repeat them again in a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my case, which is not the best solution but it works. In the `MailSenderAutoConfiguration` class there is this nested class :

```
**
 * Condition to trigger the creation of a {@link JavaMailSenderImpl}. This kicks in if
 * either the host or jndi name property is set.
 */
static class MailSenderCondition extends AnyNestedCondition {...}
```

So I just commented the `spring.mail.host` property and when I'll need to send emails I'll uncomment it. It isn't the best solution because I am sure I'll forget to uncomment it one day. 
This solution works in my case but for general needs (any auto-configuration) it will not work. I hope to see this feature on next Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation you don't have control over Spring Boot's `MailSenderAutoConfiguration`.

You could move the `spring.mail` properties into a separate `application-mail.yaml` file. It will be loaded only when Spring has an active `mail` profile (e.g. `@ActiveProfiles("mail")`). Without this `mail` profile the default `MailSenderAutoConfiguration` won't see them.

Comment: This could not work in my case because I have many property files which are enabled dependending on the active profile. If I add a new property file my app will crash. I do not have other choice than declare my own bean. I took a quick look at the code of `MailSenderAutoConfiguration` and I full have control over the bean created by Spring Boot since its properties are based on properties defined in application.properties.

Comment: @akuma8 If adding a new property file for a non-active profile crashes your app you have a bug.

Comment: The problem will be when the profile will be active because in my app I have this : `@PropertySource( value = {       "classpath:securityservice/security-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" } )` so when the `mail` profile will be active, the file `security-mail.properties` will not be found

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar case with JmsAutoConfiguration, and what have I done was:

1. Exclude in main SpringBoot class:

```
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class,JmsAutoConfiguration.class})
```

2. Create separate configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("application.queue.enabled")
@EnableJms
@ImportAutoConfiguration({ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class,JmsAutoConfiguration.class})
public class JmsConfiguration {
    ...
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

To disable AutoConfiguration by property you can create excluder configuration like that;

```
    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "app.email", value = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class MailSenderAutoConfigurationExcluder {}
```